# Error with Room dao class with Kotlin Coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, mobile-development

[Click here to see error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yEYK.png)

**Error**
error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super java.lang.Long> continuation);

** Please see the below code for my ArticleDao and ArticleDatabase Class**

**Article**

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "articles"
)

@Parcelize
data class Article(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null,
    val author: String?,
    val content: String?,
    val description: String?,
    val publishedAt: String?,
    val source: Source?,
    val title: String?,
    val url: String?,
    val urlToImage: String?
) : Parcelable
```

**Converters**

```
class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromSource(source : Source) : String{
        return source.name
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toSource(name : String) : Source {
        return Source(name, name)
    }
}
```

**ArticleDao**

```
@Dao
interface ArticleDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun upsertArticle(article : Article) : Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM articles")
    fun getAllArticles() : LiveData<List<Article>>

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteArticle(article: Article)


}
```

**ArticleDatabase**

```
@Database(
    entities = [Article::class],
    version = 1
)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class ArticleDatabase : RoomDatabase(){

    abstract fun getArticleDao() : ArticleDao

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var instance: ArticleDatabase? = null
       
        private val LOCK = Any()


        operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance ?: synchronized(LOCK) {
            instance ?: createDatase(context).also { instance = it }
        }
        
        private fun createDatase(context: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                ArticleDatabase::class.java,
                "article_db.db"
            ).build()

    }

}
```

**FYI: Room library version below**

```
 def roomVersion = "2.4.2"

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")

    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")
```

Comment: Is the Article class annotated with @Entity? You should probably add the class to your question. You should also probably add the Converters class as well.

Comment: @MikeT Thank you for your suggestion. I just added Converters and Article class code for clarification.

Comment: You should be using **`kapt`** not `annotationProcessor` for the **compiler** library, this could result in the issue as Article ends up not being a java class as expected by the annotation processor. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html#using-in-gradle if unsure how to include the plugin.